# When nesting two divs with automatic heights, how can I have the smaller one stick to the top?

Tags: css, html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
 * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }

 html, body {
  height: 100%;
 }
</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#00CC99">

<div style="position: relative;  min-height: 600px;  height: auto;  width: 800px;  border: 3px solid #000000;  padding: 10px;">
    <div style="position: relative;  display: inline-block;  min-height: 500px;  width: 300px;  border: 3px solid #000000;  overflow: auto;  padding: 10px;">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac sem sit amet dolor fermentum semper sit amet vitae lectus. Aliquam tempor blandit pharetra. Vestibulum dapibus, tellus at sagittis tempus, neque dolor consequat velit, eget feugiat est lorem eu orci. Quisque consequat consequat mi, fermentum mollis arcu pellentesque ut. Nulla ut risus risus. Vestibulum eget velit eget risus elementum interdum nec sit amet nisi. Nunc ante nunc, volutpat ac dignissim auctor, mattis sit amet metus. Integer bibendum auctor ante, ac tempor leo faucibus in. Donec leo tellus, faucibus eget sagittis a, hendrerit ut tortor. Aenean vulputate placerat suscipit. Vivamus hendrerit sem a velit bibendum malesuada pharetra non nunc. Praesent eget erat enim, sit amet rutrum leo. Mauris nulla nunc, scelerisque ac dapibus eget, facilisis eget neque. Maecenas arcu sem, elementum in rutrum nec, molestie ut massa.</p><br>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac sem sit amet dolor fermentum semper sit amet vitae lectus. Aliquam tempor blandit pharetra. Vestibulum dapibus, tellus at sagittis tempus, neque dolor consequat velit, eget feugiat est lorem eu orci. Quisque consequat consequat mi, fermentum mollis arcu pellentesque ut. Nulla ut risus risus. Vestibulum eget velit eget risus elementum interdum nec sit amet nisi. Nunc ante nunc, volutpat ac dignissim auctor, mattis sit amet metus. Integer bibendum auctor ante, ac tempor leo faucibus in. Donec leo tellus, faucibus eget sagittis a, hendrerit ut tortor. Aenean vulputate placerat suscipit. Vivamus hendrerit sem a velit bibendum malesuada pharetra non nunc. Praesent eget erat enim, sit amet rutrum leo. Mauris nulla nunc, scelerisque ac dapibus eget, facilisis eget neque. Maecenas arcu sem, elementum in rutrum nec, molestie ut massa.</p>
    </div>

    <div style="position: relative;  display: inline-block;  min-height: 500px;  width: 400px;  border: 3px solid #000000;  overflow: auto;  padding: 10px;">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac sem sit amet dolor fermentum semper sit amet vitae lectus. Aliquam tempor blandit pharetra. Vestibulum dapibus, tellus at sagittis tempus, neque dolor consequat velit, eget feugiat est lorem eu orci. Quisque consequat consequat mi, fermentum mollis arcu pellentesque ut. Nulla ut risus risus. Vestibulum eget velit eget risus elementum interdum nec sit amet nisi. Nunc ante nunc, volutpat ac dignissim auctor, mattis sit amet metus. Integer bibendum auctor ante, ac tempor leo faucibus in. Donec leo tellus, faucibus eget sagittis a, hendrerit ut tortor. Aenean vulputate placerat suscipit. Vivamus hendrerit sem a velit bibendum malesuada pharetra non nunc. Praesent eget erat enim, sit amet rutrum leo. Mauris nulla nunc, scelerisque ac dapibus eget, facilisis eget neque. Maecenas arcu sem, elementum in rutrum nec, molestie ut massa.</p><br><br>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac sem sit amet dolor fermentum semper sit amet vitae lectus. Aliquam tempor blandit pharetra. Vestibulum dapibus, tellus at sagittis tempus, neque dolor consequat velit, eget feugiat est lorem eu orci. Quisque consequat consequat mi, fermentum mollis arcu pellentesque ut. Nulla ut risus risus. Vestibulum eget velit eget risus elementum interdum nec sit amet nisi. Nunc ante nunc, volutpat ac dignissim auctor, mattis sit amet metus. Integer bibendum auctor ante, ac tempor leo faucibus in. Donec leo tellus, faucibus eget sagittis a, hendrerit ut tortor. Aenean vulputate placerat suscipit. Vivamus hendrerit sem a velit bibendum malesuada pharetra non nunc. Praesent eget erat enim, sit amet rutrum leo. Mauris nulla nunc, scelerisque ac dapibus eget, facilisis eget neque. Maecenas arcu sem, elementum in rutrum nec, molestie ut massa.</p><br><br>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac sem sit amet dolor fermentum semper sit amet vitae lectus. Aliquam tempor blandit pharetra. Vestibulum dapibus, tellus at sagittis tempus, neque dolor consequat velit, eget feugiat est lorem eu orci. Quisque consequat consequat mi, fermentum mollis arcu pellentesque ut. Nulla ut risus risus. Vestibulum eget velit eget risus elementum interdum nec sit amet nisi. Nunc ante nunc, volutpat ac dignissim auctor, mattis sit amet metus. Integer bibendum auctor ante, ac tempor leo faucibus in. Donec leo tellus, faucibus eget sagittis a, hendrerit ut tortor. Aenean vulputate placerat suscipit. Vivamus hendrerit sem a velit bibendum malesuada pharetra non nunc. Praesent eget erat enim, sit amet rutrum leo. Mauris nulla nunc, scelerisque ac dapibus eget, facilisis eget neque. Maecenas arcu sem, elementum in rutrum nec, molestie ut massa.</p>
    </div>    
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Clearly, the nested div on the left is the shorter of the two.  How can I make sure that the left div can stay at the same level from the top as the div on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `vertical-align:top` in the styles of the first (left) div works in Chrome and Firefox (didn't try IE or Safari, I assume Safari works).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
 * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }

 html, body {
  height: 100%;
 }
</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#00CC99">

<div style="min-height: 600px; height: auto; width: 800px; border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 10px; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="min-height: 500px; width: 300px; border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); overflow: auto; padding: 10px; float: left;">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac sem sit amet dolor fermentum semper sit amet vitae lectus. Aliquam tempor blandit pharetra. Vestibulum dapibus, tellus at sagittis tempus, neque dolor consequat velit, eget feugiat est lorem eu orci. Quisque consequat consequat mi, fermentum mollis arcu pellentesque ut. Nulla ut risus risus. Vestibulum eget velit eget risus elementum interdum nec sit amet nisi. Nunc ante nunc, volutpat ac dignissim auctor, mattis sit amet metus. Integer bibendum auctor ante, ac tempor leo faucibus in. Donec leo tellus, faucibus eget sagittis a, hendrerit ut tortor. Aenean vulputate placerat suscipit. Vivamus hendrerit sem a velit bibendum malesuada pharetra non nunc. Praesent eget erat enim, sit amet rutrum leo. Mauris nulla nunc, scelerisque ac dapibus eget, facilisis eget neque. Maecenas arcu sem, elementum in rutrum nec, molestie ut massa.</p><br>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac sem sit amet dolor fermentum semper sit amet vitae lectus. Aliquam tempor blandit pharetra. Vestibulum dapibus, tellus at sagittis tempus, neque dolor consequat velit, eget feugiat est lorem eu orci. Quisque consequat consequat mi, fermentum mollis arcu pellentesque ut. Nulla ut risus risus. Vestibulum eget velit eget risus elementum interdum nec sit amet nisi. Nunc ante nunc, volutpat ac dignissim auctor, mattis sit amet metus. Integer bibendum auctor ante, ac tempor leo faucibus in. Donec leo tellus, faucibus eget sagittis a, hendrerit ut tortor. Aenean vulputate placerat suscipit. Vivamus hendrerit sem a velit bibendum malesuada pharetra non nunc. Praesent eget erat enim, sit amet rutrum leo. Mauris nulla nunc, scelerisque ac dapibus eget, facilisis eget neque. Maecenas arcu sem, elementum in rutrum nec, molestie ut massa.</p>
    </div>

    <div style="min-height: 500px; width: 400px; border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); overflow: auto; padding: 10px;">

     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac sem sit amet dolor fermentum semper sit amet vitae lectus. Aliquam tempor blandit pharetra. Vestibulum dapibus, tellus at sagittis tempus, neque dolor consequat velit, eget feugiat est lorem eu orci. Quisque consequat consequat mi, fermentum mollis arcu pellentesque ut. Nulla ut risus risus. Vestibulum eget velit eget risus elementum interdum nec sit amet nisi. Nunc ante nunc, volutpat ac dignissim auctor, mattis sit amet metus. Integer bibendum auctor ante, ac tempor leo faucibus in. Donec leo tellus, faucibus eget sagittis a, hendrerit ut tortor. Aenean vulputate placerat suscipit. Vivamus hendrerit sem a velit bibendum malesuada pharetra non nunc. Praesent eget erat enim, sit amet rutrum leo. Mauris nulla nunc, scelerisque ac dapibus eget, facilisis eget neque. Maecenas arcu sem, elementum in rutrum nec, molestie ut massa.</p><br><br>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac sem sit amet dolor fermentum semper sit amet vitae lectus. Aliquam tempor blandit pharetra. Vestibulum dapibus, tellus at sagittis tempus, neque dolor consequat velit, eget feugiat est lorem eu orci. Quisque consequat consequat mi, fermentum mollis arcu pellentesque ut. Nulla ut risus risus. Vestibulum eget velit eget risus elementum interdum nec sit amet nisi. Nunc ante nunc, volutpat ac dignissim auctor, mattis sit amet metus. Integer bibendum auctor ante, ac tempor leo faucibus in. Donec leo tellus, faucibus eget sagittis a, hendrerit ut tortor. Aenean vulputate placerat suscipit. Vivamus hendrerit sem a velit bibendum malesuada pharetra non nunc. Praesent eget erat enim, sit amet rutrum leo. Mauris nulla nunc, scelerisque ac dapibus eget, facilisis eget neque. Maecenas arcu sem, elementum in rutrum nec, molestie ut massa.</p><br><br>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ac sem sit amet dolor fermentum semper sit amet vitae lectus. Aliquam tempor blandit pharetra. Vestibulum dapibus, tellus at sagittis tempus, neque dolor consequat velit, eget feugiat est lorem eu orci. Quisque consequat consequat mi, fermentum mollis arcu pellentesque ut. Nulla ut risus risus. Vestibulum eget velit eget risus elementum interdum nec sit amet nisi. Nunc ante nunc, volutpat ac dignissim auctor, mattis sit amet metus. Integer bibendum auctor ante, ac tempor leo faucibus in. Donec leo tellus, faucibus eget sagittis a, hendrerit ut tortor. Aenean vulputate placerat suscipit. Vivamus hendrerit sem a velit bibendum malesuada pharetra non nunc. Praesent eget erat enim, sit amet rutrum leo. Mauris nulla nunc, scelerisque ac dapibus eget, facilisis eget neque. Maecenas arcu sem, elementum in rutrum nec, molestie ut massa.</p>
    </div>    
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: The float left does solve the issue but negates the padding I desire to separate the divs.  Vertical-align works best for me.